# Visual Studio wont allow selecting Windows Application in project properties

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm trying to get a WPF application to run without the console showing, but Visual Studio is forcing it to be a console application.

For some reason Visual Studio is inferring that the project is a console application and not respecting the OutputType property. There are reports of this happening with `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, but I can't find any reports of it with `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`. And unlike those reports it happens when running the generated exe file directly, not just when running from Visual Studio.

From the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ImplicitUsings>true</ImplicitUsings>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    <StartupObject>MyApp.App</StartupObject>
    <ApplicationIcon>Windows\Disk.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Image of the project properties window:
[image: Visual Studio project properties showing that "Console Application" is selected as the output type.]

Comment: Create a new scratch Wpf app. Spin it up and confirm it doesn't run as a console app. Then compare your sln and csproj and remove all the settings in your current csproj which are not in the scratch one. Confirm that now works as a Wpf app rather than console. Then if you must add one setting, try it. Repeat until you find the one you chose which broke everything.  I see several odd entries in your csproj.

Comment: Does this still happen if you use .net 6.0？